# Let $\tau\in \operatorname{Aut}_K F$ and $H$ be an intermediate field. Must $\tau[H]\subseteq H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$. Let $\tau\in \operatorname{Aut}_K F$ and $H$ be an intermediate field. Must $\tau[H]\subseteq H$ ?

In case $\dim_K H\leq2$, the answer is easily yes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no in general. For example, consider an irreducible cubic $p$ (over $\mathbb Q$) with exactly one real root $r$. There is an automorphism $\tau$ of its splitting field that maps $r$ to another root of $p$, but $\mathbb Q(r)$ consists solely of real numbers, and therefore $\tau(r)\notin \mathbb Q(r)$.